# Necessary assumptions for moments/joint distribution of dependent bernoulli trials.

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

I am trying to figure out what I need to assume in a project work I am writing.

Suppose I have $N$ $0-1$ Bernoulli trials $\{B_i\}$ with success probabilities $p_i$. I know that they are positively correlated since I know their conditional distribution given another Bernoulli variable $X$ (and given my particular parameters this indeed happens). We have $B_i|X=^d Be(q_i)$ where $q_i$ is computable/known. I know that in general, the joint distribution of an $N$-dimensional Bernoulli vector is determined by the "moments" $E(B_iB_j...B_k)$ (see [Multivariate normal and multivariate Bernoulli](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/52137/multivariate-normal-and-multivariate-bernoulli/52321#52321), [Joint distribution of dependent Bernoulli Random variables](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1847233/joint-distribution-of-dependent-bernoulli-random-variables?rq=1)). However, one should think that knowing the conditional distribution is quite a bit stronger than just knowing the second moment. Is there any way I can extract more information from conditional distribution above about the joint distribution? If not, what sort of "information" would I require to compute these mixed moments?

Any help or reference would be much appreciated!

EDIT: Would it for instance suffice to know the joint distribution of $\{B_i\}$ conditional on $X$?

Comment: I may not following your question correctly, just pointing out one thing. For example in a bivariate Bernoulli, you have $2^2 = 4$ support points, so in general you need $4$ conditions to determine them. If you are given the two marginal distributions, and the sum of them must equal to $1$, so you only need $1$ more condition, e.g. given the cross moment to completely determine it.

Comment: I think you are interpreting it correctly, sort of at least. This is precisely the point that is being made in the question I linked to after my comment on the moments. The problem is that I don't really know the  moments, but I can know other things which might lead me to them (this is an aspect of the model I am working on).

Comment: So maybe you can clarify what do you want (the joint distribution of ...?) and what information do you have.