# On Probability Measures on $\{-1,+1\}^n$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, binomial-distribution

Let's put it formally...

Let $n$ be a positive integer and $E = \{-1,+1\}^n$.
Consider the set $\mathcal{P}$ of all the probability measures $\mu$ on $E$ such that
$$
\mu ( \pi_i^{-1} \{-1\} ) = \mu ( \pi_i^{-1} \{+1\} ) = \frac12 
$$
where $\pi_i : E \rightarrow \{-1,+1\}$ is the canonical projection onto the $i^\text{th}$ component of $E$, i.e. $\pi_i(x_1, \dots, x_n) = x_i$.

How can I parametrize $\mathcal{P}$?

Also, letting $\mathcal{C}$ be the set of all $n \times n$ correlation matrices, consider the map
$c: \mathcal{P} \rightarrow \mathcal{C} $ that assigns to each probability measure in $\mathcal{P}$ its correlation matrix.
Is $c$ injective? Surjective?

For the simple case $n=2$, it is clear to me that we can put $\mathcal{P}$ in a bijection with $[0,\frac12]$. For $a \in [0,\frac12]$, define $\mu$ as
$$
\mu \{-1,-1\} = \mu \{+1,+1\} = a \\
\mu \{-1,+1\} = \mu \{+1,-1\} = \frac12 - a 
$$
It's also clear that $c$ is bijective since the correlation is $4a-1$.

But what about the case of arbitrary $n$?

Comment: You might want to look into "Bernoulli copulas". This looks pertinent: [Admissible Bernoulli correlations](https://jsdajournal.springeropen.com/articles/10.1186/s40488-019-0091-5)

Comment: @gg Thanks a lot! The paper you mention answers my question. If you post an anser I ll give you the bounty.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The measures you are interested in are called symmetric Bernoulli distributions. The question which correlations are possible for such distributions is answered in the paper [Admissible Bernoulli correlations](https://jsdajournal.springeropen.com/articles/10.1186/s40488-019-0091-5).

To quote from the paper:

> Consider a vertex of the n-dimensional cube $v\in\{0,1\}^n$. For
> instance, when $n=5$, $v=(0,0,1,0,1)$ is such a vertex. Let 1 denote
> the vector of all 1’s. Then for any $v\in\{0,1\}^n$, the distribution
> $\text{Unif}(\{v,1−v\})$ (discrete uniform distribution over two
> points: $v$ and $1−v$) has marginals that are all uniform over the
> pair $\{0,1\}$. Hence all such distributions are multivariate
> symmetric Bernoulli.
>
> Any convex combination of multivariate symmetric Bernoulli
> distributions will also be multivariate symmetric Bernoulli. Our main
> result is that any admissible correlation structure can also be
> realized as the correlation structure of such a convex combination.

They further characterize (in their Theorem 2) all possible correlations of symmetric Bernoulli distributions in terms of the $\text{CUT}_n$ polytope.

Answer (score 1):

> How can I parametrize $\mathcal{P}$?

[This answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/52137/multivariate-normal-and-multivariate-bernoulli/52321#52321) should help.

Taking the example ($n=3$), and given that here the marginals are uniform, hence $E[X_i]=0$, we have the parametrization

$$ P(x_1,x_2,x_3)=\frac{1}{2^3}\left( a_{123} x_1 x_2 x_3 +  
a_{12} x_1 x_2  + a_{23} x_2 x_3  + a_{13} x_1 x_3  + 
1
\right) $$

where $a_{i...k}=E[X_i ... X_k]$. In particular, here, $a_{i,j}=E[X_i X_j] = C_{i,j}$ for $i\ne j$.

(Obvioulsy $C_{i,i}=1$)

I think this answers your second question. Fixing the covariance matrix only fixes the second-order terms (just as fixing the marginals fixes the first order terms). This gives a one-to-one mapping only for the bivariate case. For $n>2$ there are additional terms, which correspond to additional degrees of freedom.
Hence, for a given covariance matrix there exist (in general) several (infinite) distributions.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the insight